# Extracting rar files having the same password

Tags: batch, unzip, rar

I use `unrar` to extract rar files on Ubuntu 18.04.
How can I extract 100 files that have the same password without giving the password 100 times.
I hope I can do it on Nautilus, also terminal is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you can do that in nautilus. In a terminal you can do it with

```
unrar x -ppassword <files...>
```

if you want to use the included path names. Type `man unrar` to see other options.

Comment: `unrar x -ppassword './*.rar'` this works for me.

Comment: it is inconvenient that I can not do it in file manager,

Comment: @Ives: I imagine that it's a relatively uncommon requirement and thus has a low priority for the developers. You're welcome to create a file manager extension that does this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the same password is for multiple split parts, so what I need is:

```
unrar x -p<your_password> <1st_rar_filepath> ./<output_main_directory>/
```

Note:

1. You only need to provide the first `.rar` filepath, then it will extract the rest of the rar files automatically.
2. Ensure output directory name trailing with `/`.

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Comment: works like a charm. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

... And use

```
ls myfile*.rar | xargs -n1 rar x -ppassword
```

to unpack all (100) files

Comment: [Useless use of `ls`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls).

Comment: How is ls useless ? Sure you could use echo or find to create a list of all rar files, but why is that better?

Comment: Not exactly useless but kind of dangerous due to how unpredictably it handles special characters. `printf '%s\0' FILES... | xargs -0 ...` or a plain old `for` loop with properly quoted variables would be much better.